# Access Denied when trying to change password from c#

Tags: winforms, active-directory, access-denied, citrix, change-password

I wrote a tool that allows users to change their AD-password. This tool works without problems on my companies domain, but when running it on our customers machine with citrix I receive the following error message:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] args)
>     at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SDSUtils.ChangePassword(DirectoryEntry de, String oldPassword, String newPassword)
>     at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.ChangePassword(AuthenticablePrincipal p, String oldPassword, String newPassword)
>     at CitrixPWChangeBackend.ActiveDirectory.ChangePasswordForCurrentUser(String oldPw, String newPw, Boolean& errorWrongPw, Boolean& errorPasswordRules, String& errorMessage)

The Line causing that Error is:

```
UserPrincipal.Current.ChangePassword(oldPw, newPw);
```

"oldPW" is correct, of course

Comment: Can you run the tool successfully using the same user but logged into the console of one of your customer's machines? It would be good to do that to rule out Citrix, as an access denied exception is not something I would expect the Citrix environment to introduce.

Comment: Meanwhile I found out, that the user has the property UserCannotChangePassword set to true. After ripping off the administrators head I wait to get another account to correctly test my code.

Comment: Thanks, donovan. The reason was on the configuration side as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "magic" reason was a policy for that user causing the property "UserCannotChangePassword" to be true. 
No Citrix specific issue.