# Active Directory access denied exception on DirectoryEntry.Invoke ChangePassword

Tags: c#, active-directory

Following MVC web api code works without errors

```
directoryEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", "desired password");
directoryEntry.CommitChanges();
```

But same application/service account get an error when attempting

```
directoryEntry.Invoke("ChangePassword", "old password", "new password");
directoryEntry.CommitChanges();
```

Error details:
`System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))`

Does invoking ChangePassword require different permissions that SetPassword?

Comment: Is it possible that the "change password" flag is unchecked for that user?

Comment: @Cory Can you please tell how can I verify that?

Comment: @Cory Sorry was being lazy. Found that flag in user properties, and it was checked (User Cannot Change Password). Unchecked it and error went away. If you add it as an answer I will mark it as answer. BTW new error is "The specified network password is not correct. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070056)" Even though I'm entering the correct current password.

Comment: nevermind last comment's new error part...serialization error.

Comment: That's good news. I converted my comment-question to an answer.

Comment: Also I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971736/access-denied-when-trying-to-change-password-from-c-sharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be getting the access denied error due to the "User cannot change password" setting flag being checked. Any users for which you want to allow their password to be changed will need that setting unchecked.

Answer (score 2):

check your application pool identity user in IIS7 set the user which has the admin rights to change the AD password

you can find it under iis 7 >> application pools then select the application pool which your application using then  right click on it and select advance setting then locate Process Model under this you will find Identity attribute here set the correct user which has admin rights